# Nested dictionary keeps overwriting data

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to read in from a data file that has lines like:

```
2007 ANDREA 30 31.40 -71.90 05/13/18Z 25 1007 LOW

2007 ANDREA 31 31.80 -69.40 05/14/00Z 25 1007 LOW
```

I am trying to create a nested dictionary that has a key holding the year and then the nested dictionary will hold the name and a tuple containing statistics. I would like the return value to look like this:

```
{'2007': {'ANDREA': [(31.4, -71.9, '05/13/18Z', 25.0, 1007.0), (31.8, -69.4, '05/14/00Z', 25.0, 1007.0)]
```

However when I run the code it returns only one set of statistics. It seems to be overwriting itself because I am getting that last line of statistics in the txt file returned:

```
{'2007': {'ANDREA': [(31.8, -69.4, '05/14/00Z', 25.0, 1007.0)]
```

Here is the code:

```
def create_dictionary(fp):
'''Remember to put a docstring here'''
   dict1 = {}
   f = []
   for line in fp:
       a = line.split()
       f.append(a)
   for item in f:
       a = (float(item[3]), float(item[4]), item[5], float(item[6]), 
   float(item[7]))

       dict1 = update_dictionary(dict1, item[0], item[1], a))                                        

   print(dict1)

def update_dictionary(dictionary, year, hurricane_name, data):

   if year not in dictionary:
        dictionary[year] = {}

        if hurricane_name not in dictionary:
            dictionary[year][hurricane_name] = [data]

        else:
            dictionary[year][hurricane_name].append(data)      

    else:    
        if hurricane_name not in dictionary:
            dictionary[year][hurricane_name] = [data]

        else:
            dictionary[year][hurricane_name].append(data)

    return dictionary
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines:

```
    if hurricane_name not in dictionary:
```

...should be:

```
    if hurricane_name not in dictionary[year]:
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I was a little late here's a suggestion instead of an answer to your original question. You can simplify the logic a bit because when the year doesn't exist then the name also can't exist for that year. Everything can be put in a single function and using a "with" statement to open the file will ensure it is properly closed even if your program encounters an error.

```
def build_dict(file_path):

    result = {}

    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:

        for line in f:

            items = line.split()

            year, name, data = items[0], items[1], tuple(items[2:])

            if year in result:

                if name in result[year]:

                    result[year][name].append(data)

                else:

                    result[year][name] = [data]

            else:

                result[year] = {name: [data]}

    return result


print(build_dict(file_path))
```

Output:

```
{'2007': {'ANDREA': [('30', '31.40', '-71.90', '05/13/18Z', '25', '1007', 'LOW'), ('31', '31.80', '-69.40', '05/14/00Z', '25', '1007', 'LOW')]}}
```